# Prevent input to submit html code/script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

I am creating a directory where the users are able to post articles. To get the values to be posted I am using inputs html elements and using `$.post` to save the data in the database.

However, I have a problem that if an user writes some html code in the article it is saved formatting the code.

for example if the value entered is:

```
<input type="text" value="this is an article title <script>$("body").remove();</script>">
```

when the post is submitted the page will load also the js script removing the `body`.

How can avoid this and tell that in the input field there is a script, or formatting the script to show as a text?

Comment: You need to sanitise user inputs on the server - JS/jQuery is not the right tool for this job as it's far too easy to get around.

Comment: I have to do it on my php get?

Comment: Check out [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php).

Comment: thanks a lot it works ----- `$title = htmlspecialchars(filter_input(INPUT_GET, "title"), ENT_QUOTES);`

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

//Simple answer
#when you echo data results from the database. consider code below..
#Assuming you are at the last process of echoling the data out.
$data='THIS WOULD BE YOUR DATA OBJECT OR VARIABLE CONTAINING DATA FROM THE DATABASE';


#then...
$data=htmlentities($data);
#or
$data=strip_tags($data);
#or
$data=htmlspecialchars($data);


#just be assured that tags or code will not be executed by the browser once above is included!
echo $data;
```

Comment: Thanks but when I return the data I return it as a json

Comment: then json encode your data. like       ==>  $data=json_encode(htmlspecialchars($data));